# Antlr4 extraneous input even though it's necessary?

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I am new to writing Antlr grammars and I'm having some trouble. I have simplified my issue down to the following:

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar Test;

prog    :   stmt*       ;
stmt    :   INT NEWLINE ;

INT     :   [0-9]+      ;
NEWLINE :   '\r'? '\n'  ;
```

My input.txt is simply `0\r\n` (not the literals '\', 'r', '\', 'n', but the ASCII codes `0x0D 0x0A`

I get the following error:

```
line 1:1 extraneous input '\r\n' expecting {<EOF>, INT}
```

Why does it expect another `INT` without first matching a `NEWLINE` when the `stmt` rule requires that the `INT` be followed by a `NEWLINE`?

If it's relevant, I'm using PyCharm and the Antlr4 plugin to do the grammar generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was related to Python's odd behavior when running modules that import modules that have been altered (hint: they're not automatically reloaded as they should be). The solution was to simply restart the interpreter when you change the grammar.

I'm sorry that the original question didn't have enough information for anyone else to figure out that answer.